# IRC server segfault when clients, send more than 10 messages

Tags: c

When client send more than 10 messages,the server segfault but the server havn't this problem. he can send not restricted numbers of messages.

it's probably caused by my char *buffer malloc() and badly free() maybe ???
i have try to use static array buffer without free() evidently but it's worst.

Client

```
#include "header.h"

void    app(SOCKET socket)
{
    char pseudo[24];
    int statu;
    fd_set readfs;

    strcpy(pseudo, "[");
    strcat(pseudo, getname(sizeof(pseudo)));
    strcat(pseudo, "] ");

    while (1)
    {
        char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
        char *msg = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);

        FD_ZERO(&readfs);
        FD_SET(socket, &readfs);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfs);

        if (select(socket + 1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
        {
            perror("select()");
            exit(errno);
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfs))
        {
            fgets(msg, sizeof(char) * 1000, stdin);
            strcpy(buffer, pseudo);
            strcat(buffer, msg);
            send_message(socket, buffer);
            cleanMsg(buffer, msg);
        }
        else if (FD_ISSET(socket, &readfs))
        {
            statu = receive_message(socket, buffer);
            if (statu == 0)
            {
                printf("Server disconnected !\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
                cleanMsg(buffer, msg);
            }
        }
    }
    close_connection(socket);
}

void    send_message(SOCKET socket, char *buffer)
{   
    int i;

    for (i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n'; i++) ;
    buffer[i] = '\0';

    if (send(socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("send()");
        exit(errno);
    }
}

int receive_message(SOCKET socket, char *buffer)
{
    int statu = 0;
    if ((statu = recv(socket, buffer, 1024, 0)) < 0)
        perror("recv()");
    return statu;
}

void    cleanMsg(char *buffer, char *msg)
{
    memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer));
    memset(msg, 0, strlen(msg));
    free(buffer);
    free(msg);
}

char    *getname(size_t namesize)
{
    char *tmp = NULL;

    tmp = malloc(namesize);
    getlogin_r(tmp, namesize);

    return tmp;
}
```

Server:

```
#include "header.h"

int app(SOCKET master_socket, serv_config *s_conf)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN client_address = {0};
    SOCKET new_socket;
    int address_size = sizeof(client_address);
    int *clients_socket = NULL;
    int statu = 0;
    int fdmax;
    int sd;
    int i;

    clients_socket = malloc(sizeof(int) * s_conf->max_client);

    fd_set readfs;

    for (i = 0; i < s_conf->max_client; i++)
        clients_socket[i] = 0;

    while (1)
    {

        char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
        char *msg = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);

        FD_ZERO(&readfs);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfs);
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfs);

        fdmax = master_socket;

        for (i = 0; i < s_conf->max_client; i++)
        {
            sd = clients_socket[i];
            if (sd > 0)
                FD_SET(sd, &readfs);
            if (sd > fdmax)
                fdmax = sd;
        }

        if (select(fdmax + 1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
        {
            perror("select()");
            exit(errno);
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfs))
        {
            fgets(msg, sizeof(char) * 1000, stdin);
            strcpy(buffer, "[Server] ");
            strcat(buffer, msg);
            send_toall(clients_socket, 0, s_conf->max_client, buffer);
            cleanMsg(buffer, msg);
        }
        else if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfs))
        {
            new_socket = accept(master_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&client_address, &address_size);

            if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                perror("accept()");
                closesocket(new_socket);
                exit(errno);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < s_conf->max_client; i++)
            {
                if (clients_socket[s_conf->max_client - 1] != 0)
                {
                    strcpy(buffer, "Connection error: no more client can be connected.\n");
                    send_message(new_socket, buffer);
                    cleanMsg(buffer, msg);
                    shutdown(new_socket, 2);
                    closesocket(new_socket);
                    break;
                }
                else if (clients_socket[i] == 0)
                {
                    clients_socket[i] = new_socket;
                    printf("New client connected with socket %d from %s:%d, in slot %d\n", clients_socket[i], inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr), ntohs(client_address.sin_port), i);
                    strcpy(buffer, "Success connecting.\n");
                    send_message(clients_socket[i], buffer);
                    cleanMsg(buffer, msg);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < s_conf->max_client; i++)
            {
                if (FD_ISSET(clients_socket[i], &readfs))
                {
                    statu = receive_message(clients_socket[i], buffer);
                    if (statu == 0)
                    {
                        printf("Socket %d Disconnect\n", clients_socket[i]);
                        shutdown(clients_socket[i], 2);
                        closesocket(clients_socket[i]);
                        clients_socket[i] = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        send_toall(clients_socket, clients_socket[i], s_conf->max_client, buffer);
                        cleanMsg(buffer, msg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return *clients_socket;
}

void    send_toall(int *clients_socket, int actual_socket, int max, char *buffer)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; clients_socket[i] < max; i++)
    {
        if (clients_socket[i] != actual_socket && clients_socket[i] != 0)
            send_message(clients_socket[i], buffer);
    }
}

void    send_message(SOCKET socket, char *buffer)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n'; i++) ;
    buffer[i] = '\0';

    if (send(socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("send()");
        exit(errno);
    }
}

int receive_message(SOCKET socket, char *buffer)
{
    int statu = 0;
    if ((statu = recv(socket, buffer, 1024, 0)) < 0)
        perror("recv()");
    return statu;
}

void cleanMsg(char *buffer, char *msg)
{
    memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer));
    memset(msg, 0, strlen(msg));
    free(buffer);
    free(msg);
}
```

Server just segfault and quit after client sending more than 10 messages.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to find where it segfaults?

Comment: Yes i have use Valgrind but nothing :/

Comment: Valgrind helps you find memory leaks, it's not a debugger as such. Look at `gdb`.

Comment: I don't see a `main` anywhere. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Yes a know, it's just the minimal require to probably solve the problem :/

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is by definition always 1, or the language you are using is not C.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem solved, just replace this:

```
    for (i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n'; i++) ;
    buffer[i] = '\0';
```

by this:

```
    for (i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n' && buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) ;
    buffer[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have significant issues with the way you are sending and receiving messages.

First, you completely ignore the fact that TCP connections are *streams* with no concept of message boundaries.  If you make two calls to `send()` with each sending 10 bytes, it's possible for the peer to `recv()` anything from 1 to 20 bytes, in any combination of multiple `recv()` calls, until the entire 20 bytes are received.  *You* have to figure out how to separate them into the two original messages.

Second, you have no idea how many bytes you actually receive, yet you treat the received data as a NUL-terminated string.  `recv()` doesn't NUL-terminate data, so you have to do it yourself - **after** you determine where the message boundaries are.